# Can't find plugins menu in IDA toolbar

Tags: ida

I'm using IDA pro 7.5 and I want to activate a plugin that I put in the plugins dir. in every tutorial I saw, I need to go to Edit -> Plugins and use the plugin but there is no Plugins menu in Edit.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `output window` when you start IDA, if the plugin is not loaded, it will display the error. If the author added some print statements you will see them too.
You can also start IDA with `-z20` for plugin debug (see `idat -h`).