# Python plugins won't show up in IDA 7.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, plugins, ida

I'm trying to test my plugin (python 2.7) on IDA 7.5 32-bit and every plugin that I add won't show up in Edit -> Plugins. that includes test plugins I brought from the SDK so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Have you installed Ida in Python2 or Python3 mode?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be similar to this one: [Can't find plugins menu in IDA toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65214439/cant-find-plugins-menu-in-ida-toolbar)
I posted an answer that might help.